# Where is the recalculate normals button?

Tags: modeling, interface

I really need that **[ RECALCULATE ]** button, from my tutorial. It should be here:

[image: Foto from Blender's "Wheres My Button" Page]

But it's missing:

[image: Reality :D]

What did i do wrong? The Tutorial said, select the whole Mesh with [a], so i did.. But the button is not there!

Answer (score 8):

Its in the shading/uv tab of the tools panel, on the left. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to perform the action. If you can't find a button or remember the shortcut, you can use the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu to try searching for it

Comment: @SimonDülpers If this helped you please mark it as accepted using the checkmark